# What are the exact rules for structure alignment on iPhone OS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm using the Objective-C NSMethodSignature / @encode facilities to do some cross-language data type translation, which means that I need to be able to programmatically copy values into a structure described in @encode() format.  e.g., I may have 4 floats and need to insert them into a CGRect, which is a structure containing 2 structures, each of which contains 2 floats each.  In @encode terminology, the type is this:

```
{CGRect={CGPoint=ff}{CGSize=ff}}
```

To do this I need to be able to guess the structure layout knowing only the data types of the primitive structure members -- in this case 4 floats.

It appears that historically there have been two different conventions for ARM struct alignment.  One was to align all members of the struct on a boundary size which would satisfy the largest member.  The other was to align all members on the boundary size appropriate to each member's data type.

Which is used in OS X / iPhone OS, both on ARM and on x86 / x86_64?

Comment: I mis-understood what you were trying to do and upon reviewing it closer I still don't have a good grasp. Can you explain more about how you are trying to using this information. Are you trying to dynamically create structures in another language? Are you trying to move data from one to the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to encode a CGRect you should probably use the UIGeometryKeyedCoding category addition for NSCoder -encodeCGRect:forKey:.

If you are wanting to go between systems you might consider converting the CGRect to an NSRect using NSRectFromCGRect() and then encoding the NSRect using -encodeValueOfObjCType:at:.

If you are wanting to encode other C structures Apple has a very clear policy laid out in the documentation labled 'Encoding and Decoding C Data Types'. As it states under 'Structures and Bit Fields', "The best technique for archiving a structure or a collection of bit fields is to archive the fields independently and chose the appropriate type of encoding/decoding method for each."

Comment: Interesting, and thank you for the answer.  But I need to find a general answer for all struct types using only the information derived from the @encode() string -- e.g., no knowledge of equivalence between NSRect and CGRect, no custom code per struct type, etc.